# static variable size comparison

Tags: c, static, size

Consider the following 3 programs:

1. static1.c

   ```
    int main(int argc, char * argv[])
    {
        return 0;
    }
   ```
2. static2.c

   ```
    int main(int argc, char * argv[])
    {    
        static int i;
        return 0;
    }
   ```
3. static3.c

   ```
    int main(int argc, char * argv[])
    {  
        static int i = 2;
        return 0;
    }
   ```

Now the size for each program is invoked:

1. size static1.out

   ```
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   1418     544       8    1970     7b2 static1.out
   ```
2. size static2.out

   ```
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   1418     544       8    1970     7b2 static2.out
   ```
3. size static3.out

   ```
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   1418     548       4    1970     7b2 static3.out
   ```

Why is the size output same for static1.c and static2.c, even if there is an uninitialised/zero initialised static variable in static2.out, which must go to .bss segment?

In all 3 programs the variable is never used. If the compiler is smart enough to deduce that, then why did the size information in static3.c different from other two?

If the .data and .bss are 544 and 8 respectively(without any variables), then only .data segment should change in the static3.c but from the output we can see that the int moved from .bss to .data(because the variable has an initial value now)

Comment: The compiler probably deduced that `i` isn't used in static2.c so there's no need to allocate space for it.  And I guess you didn't notice that `data` got correspondingly *bigger* in static3.c.

Comment: How did you compile? Optimization has some effect...

Comment: I compiled with -O0

Comment: And if you compile with `-Os` the result may be different. As with `-Wunused-variable -Werror`. Or with another compiler. What exactly are you blaming on the compiler if you didn't specifically tell it how to behave?